# python3 division operator exactly like in python2

Tags: python

I (really, really) need division operator in Python3 behaves like in Python2.

Python2 code:

```
--> 11/5
2
--> 11.0/5
2.2
```

But in Python3 we have

```
--> 11//5
2
--> 11.0//5
2.0
```

I can change / to // or whatever, but I expect the same results.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't make the Python 3 `/` operator behave like the Python 2 one.  If you want integer division is Python 3, you must use `//`.  There is no way to get an operator in Python 3 that sometimes does integer division and sometimes does float division; the whole point of changing this in Python 3 was to cleanly separate those two operations.  You would need to write your own function that checks the types and uses the operator you want.

Comment: Do you really need *one* operator that does floor division for ints and true division for floats, or can you use the appropriate operator for the appropriate types?

Comment: I really need that feature because my css preprocessor serves arithmetic operations to users by eval(). And for CSS that behavior was perfect: VALUE_IN_PIXELS/2 -> integer, FLOAT_VALUE_IN_EM -> float

Comment: ".. by eval()". Bzzz. Fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make it work like that. You'll have to use `/` and `//` when appropriate.

If, for some reason, you need the "polymorphism" of the old operator, you can...

```
def div(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, int):
        return a // b
    else:
        return a / b
```

Comment: OK. Because it's not possible, I just truncate result when input was all integers. I mean input of my arithmetic calculator which is provide by eval() in one css preprocessor I'm developing.

Comment: and in python2 i use import __future__

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, for support of your old code. It works with other keywords too.

```py
from __future__ import division
```

I hope it helps